# int64 to HHMM string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following data frame where the column hour shows hours of the day in int64 form. I'm trying to convert that into a time format; so that hour 1 would show up as '01:00'. I then want to add this to the date column and convert it into a timestamp index.

[image]

Using the `datetime` function in pandas resulted in the column "hr2", which is not what I need. I'm not sure I can even apply `datetime` directly, as the original data (i.e. in column "hr") is not really a date time format to begin with. Google searches so far have been unproductive.

Comment: What format is the data in the `date` column in?

Comment: thanks! the date reads as an object (when I type df.dtypes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am still in the dark concerning the format of your date column.  I will assume the Date column is a string object and the hr column is an int64 object.  To create the column TimeStamp in pandas tmestamp format this is how I would proceed>

Given df:

```
    Date    Hr
0   12/01/2010  1
1   12/01/2010  2
2   12/01/2010  3
3   12/01/2010  4
4   12/02/2010  1
5   12/02/2010  2
6   12/02/2010  3
7   12/02/2010  4  

df['TimeStamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(row['Hr'], unit='H'), axis = 1)
```

yields:

```
    Date    Hr  TimeStamp
0   12/01/2010  1   2010-12-01 01:00:00
1   12/01/2010  2   2010-12-01 02:00:00
2   12/01/2010  3   2010-12-01 03:00:00
3   12/01/2010  4   2010-12-01 04:00:00
4   12/02/2010  1   2010-12-02 01:00:00
5   12/02/2010  2   2010-12-02 02:00:00
6   12/02/2010  3   2010-12-02 03:00:00
7   12/02/2010  4   2010-12-02 04:00:00
```

The timestamp column can then be used as your index.

Comment: Will this handle **`hr`** equal to `24` correctly?

Comment: yes sir. It's simply hourly price data from ercot.com. So each day will have 24 prices; one price per hour. located here if interested: https://www.ercot.com/mktinfo/prices. Timedelta was exactly what I needed; I kept searching for the wrong thing. thanks!

Comment: user3654852: I asked because `2010-12-02 24:00:00` wouldn't be a valid date & time (and the result should be a timestamp of  `2010-12-03 00:00:00`).

Comment: I don't know for certain, but you can always test it yourself.  I believe it will cause the date to roll over to next day at 0:00 hrs